# How to use map function on a list which contains tuples as elements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-3.x, tuples

I am trying to use map function on a list of tuples. each tuple has three elements and I want to test each element in the tuple with nested if as follow.

```
def decision(*sm):
    smoker=sm[0]
    age=sm[1]
    diet=sm[2]
    if smoker=="yes":
        if age<29.5:
            return "less risk"
        elif age>29.5:
            return "more risk"
    elif smoker=="no":
        if diet=="good":
            return "less risk"
        elif diet=="poor":
            return "more risk" 

health=[('yes', 21, 'poor'), ('no', 50, 'good')]
print list(map(decision,health))
```

It gives error `tuple index out of range`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `map(..)` treats the first argument as a function (callable) and in each invocation it passes one element of the second argument (which it iterates over). With that in mind, you have to make the following fix:

Remove variable arguments, and accept a list instead:

```
def decision(sm):  #Remove '*'
```